# convert string Time to 12 hour format in React

Tags: reactjs

I have passed the showtime as a parameter and I want to convert it to 12 hour format
following is my code

```
componentDidMount() {
  let movieInfo = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search)
  console.log(movieInfo.movieid) 
  this.setState(movieInfo)
  console.log(movieInfo.name)          
  movieData = movieInfo         
}
```

my URL : is http://localhost:3000/#/seat-booking?showtimes=**2130**

I want to convert the "***2130***" into **9.30 PM**. Any suggestions??

Comment: Nothing in the code you've pasted refers to a `showtimes` parameter. Are you looking to format `2130` as `9:30 PM` for display in general?

Comment: @AKX yes. I added it to show that I get the data from queryString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, maybe.

This assumes `s` is either 3 characters (`930`) or 4 characters (`2130`) but does absolutely no other validation.

```
function militaryTimeTo12Hour(s) {
    if(s.length == 3) s = `0${s}`; // 930 -> 0930
    const hour = parseInt(s.substring(0, 2), 10);
    const min = parseInt(s.substring(2, 4), 10);
    if(hour < 12) return `${hour % 12}:${min} AM`;
    return `${hour % 12 || 12}:${min} PM`;
}
```

```
> militaryTimeTo12Hour("1230")
"12:30 PM"
> militaryTimeTo12Hour("2130")
"9:30 PM"
> militaryTimeTo12Hour("330")
"3:30 AM"
> militaryTimeTo12Hour("zquz")
"12:NaN PM"
> militaryTimeTo12Hour("3314")
"9:14 PM"
> militaryTimeTo12Hour("-799")
"-7:99 AM"
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use moment.js

```
moment('2130', 'hhmm').format('h:mm A')
```

Comment: You absolutely don't need to plug in Moment.js for something that can be done with about 7 lines of code...

Comment: this doesn't mean that the provided answer is wrong. please provide an acceptable reason for the downvote.

Comment: (I didn't downvote it, FWIW. Just noting that that's not something you'd want to add a dependency for.)