# How to change time formate in 24 in React-big-calender slots

Tags: react-native

let start = moment(el.StartDate).format('HH:mm')
not able to change the 24 hours format in react-big-calender please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
let start = moment(el.StartDate).format("hh:mm a")
```

this should work.

but In case it didn't work here is another solution.

This assumes s is either 3 characters (930) or 4 characters (2130) but does absolutely no other validation.

```
function militaryTimeTo12Hour(s) {
    if(s.length == 3) s = `0${s}`; // 930 -> 0930
    const hour = parseInt(s.substring(0, 2), 10);
    const min = parseInt(s.substring(2, 4), 10);
    if(hour < 12) return `${hour % 12}:${min} AM`;
    return `${hour % 12 || 12}:${min} PM`;
}
```

resource : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68575347/6654562